# Silverlight and SharePoint Presentation issues

Tags: permissions, silverlight, browser-compatibility, bi

A small subset of users (2 at the moment) are unable to see data presented in a Silverlight Dashboard hosted on SharePoint.  When they open the page they see empty Dashboards with no data.  I have verified permissions are correct. Any suggestion for further troubleshooting?

Comment: You will need to add a little more detail.  What is the difference between the users?  different browsers, external vs internal, etc.  Also pull up a Fiddler trace and compare the difference between a working and non-working users.

Comment: Could be a permissions issue as well but not enough information to go on here.

Comment: Dashboards fetch data from some lists and those 2 users are having permissions to those lists but still can't access

Comment: Jesus, both are internal users